# Running True/False statements on coordinates stored in two separate documents

Tags: python, excel, pandas, math, coordinates

still pretty new to this all so any help, advice, etc is really appreciated.

Heres my code:

```
import math
import pandas
file1 = pandas.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
file2 = pandas.read_excel('Book2.xlsx')
file1['RA_diff'] = file2['RA'] - file1['RA']
file1['DEC_diff'] = file2['DEC'] - file1['DEC']
dist = file1.apply(lambda row: math.hypot(row['RA_diff'], row['DEC_diff']),   axis=1)
if dist.values >= 5:
    print False
elif dist.values <= 5:
    print True, dist
```

However when I run this code I get:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

I think I understand that I am trying to make it read two separate values because without the T/F command just (print dist) I get:

```
0    4.472136
```

So, I dont know what to call it but my suspicion is that I am trying to make it read the zero value and/or multiple values.

Can anybody please explain what exactly I am doing wrong here and how to possibly fix it? Many thanks in advance!

By the way the points in the documents are labeled and appear as such in the excel sheet:

Book 1:

```
x   y
8   -5
```

Book 2:

```
x   y
12  -3
```

Comment: When you `print dist` do you know what `0` and `4.472136` refer to?

Comment: I know that the 4.472136 number if referring to the linear distance of the two points or more specifically in this case, the hypotenuse between them. But as for the 0, I have no idea.

Comment: `0` is the index of this value `4.472146`. That's what a series or dataframe is: indices associated with values (one value in the case of a series, two or more in the case of a dataframe). Now, were you expecting your series dist to have exactly one index and value in it?

Comment: OK that makes more sense, and yes, is there a way I can have the code ignore the unnecessary part of the series? Or should I try a different approach in analyzing the data? Because after I get this piece down, the data set is going to become much more complicated, with using nested for loops to compare a large list of coordinates across the two tables.

Comment: To get just the values of a series, use: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html

Comment: I am a little confused by your example, though. `dist` shouldn't actually have a single distance in it, should it? Assuming `dist` should have multiple values, even if you do `dist.values` in your boolean expression, you'll have problems.

Comment: I'm not sure then, I am using this way specifically because that seemed to be the most efficient method of determining linear distance. And had worked for every two point possibility that I've thrown at it so far.

Comment: Okay, well just try dist.values in your booleans and report back.

Comment: dist.values = file1.apply(lambda row: math.hypot(row['RA_diff'], row['DEC_diff']), axis=1)
    print dist.values

Like this?

Comment: Not quite. Leave `dist = file1.apply(lambda row: math.hypot(row['RA_diff'], row['DEC_diff']),   axis=1)` like it was. That'll make dist into a pandas series. then, replace `dist` with `dist.values` in your boolean expressions inside your `if` and `elif` statements.

Comment: OK, tried that, changed the above code just to make sure Im understanding, and got the exact same error message

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear: this is what you want to do: `if dist.values >= 5:
    print False
elif dist.values <= 5:
    print True, dist`

Comment: Ahh OK, made the change above and heres the result:  

    True 0    4.472136

Comment: Okay, this sounds like it's working closer to what you expected? What I'm still a little puzzled by, though, is why you only have a single row in `dist`? I imagine that `file1` and `file2` had multiple rows in each one, correct?

Comment: No, actually each table only has one row but two columns designated X and Y. I couldn't figure out how to edit the table above to look right so thats probably a big part of the issue. But yes this seems to be very close indeed to what I am hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
if dist.values >= 5:
    print False
```

`dist.values` is a pandas series.  You even proved this when you printed and got `0    4.472136`.  When you compare a series to a number, you get another series where each member of the series is a boolean value.  The problem lies in the fact that you are trying to evaluate the truthiness of the series itself.

So to recap, the series `dist.values >= 5` is a series of truth values.  `if dist.values >= 5` is attempting to determine wheter `dist.values >= 5` is true or not.  And that doesn't make sense.

If you want to truth of the one item in the series:

```
if dist.value[0] >= 5:
```

Or:

```
if (dist.value >= 5)[0]:
```

If you want to know if any of the items, even though there is only one, is true:

```
if (dist.values >= 5).any()
```

Or all values are true:

```
if (dist.values >= 5).all()
```

With the single value in the series, these will all evaluate to be the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the in depth lesson, this is exactly what I was hoping to get! Feel like I learned a lot from that.

Comment: Just really quick though, when I fixed the code to: 
    if (dist.values)[0] >= 5:
I still got the same output:
    True 0    0.485278